# Stop database write when throwing an exception in an EventSubscriber

Tags: php, api, symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I am working php 7.1 and Symfony 4.2 Framework.

I'm using method of dispatch($GenericEvent).İn GenericEvent I throw Exception, but in this case database write must be stopped.

I have EventSubsribersInterface class

I'm using API PLATFORM bundle. I can catch old data in kernel.request, EventPriorities::PRE_READ.

```
class KernelViewSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    const PUT = "Api Üzerinden Data Güncelleme İsteği Yapılmıştır. ";

    const POST = "Api Üzerinden Yeni Data Eklenmiştir. ";

    /**
     * @var EventDispatcherInterface
     */
    private $dispatcher;
    /**
     * @var MonologApiService
     */
    private $monologApiService;
    /**
     * @var WriteHistoryLog
     */
    private $writeHistoryLog;

    public function __construct(EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher, MonologApiService $monologApiService,WriteHistoryLog $writeHistoryLog)
    {
        $this->dispatcher = $dispatcher;
        $this->monologApiService = $monologApiService;
        $this->writeHistoryLog = $writeHistoryLog;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::VIEW => ['SystemControl', EventPriorities::PRE_VALIDATE]
        ];
    }

    public function SystemControl(GetResponseForControllerResultEvent $event, $eventKey = "")
    {
        $request = json_decode($event->getRequest()->getContent());
        $data = $event->getControllerResult();
        $method = $event->getRequest()->getMethod();
        if ($method == 'GET') {
            return;
        }
        if ($method == 'PUT') {
            $oldData = (object)$event->getRequest()->cookies->get("old");
            $eventKey = $this->putExceptions($oldData, $data ,$request);
        }
        if ($method == 'POST') {
            $eventKey = $this->postExceptions($data,$request);
            $oldData = null;
        }

        if (empty($eventKey)) {
            return;
        }
        $mixArray = array("old" => $oldData, "new" => $data,"request"=>$request,"method"=>$method);
        foreach ($eventKey as $event) {

/*İn this code section I'm trying to throw exception*/
            $genericEvent = new GenericEvent($mixArray);
            $this->dispatcher->dispatch($event, $genericEvent);
/*İn this code section I'm trying to throw exception*/
        }
        return;
    }

    /**
     * @param $oldData
     * @param $newData
     * @param array $eventKey
     * @return array
     */
    public function putExceptions($oldData, $newData, $request, $eventKey = array()): array
    {
        if ($newData instanceof Task) {
            $changeData = new HowChangeDataForTask($oldData, $newData);
            $eventKey = $changeData->checkChange();
            $this->setLog($oldData, $newData, 'PUT', self::PUT, 'Task');
        }

        if ($newData instanceof SubTask) {
            $changeData = new HowChangeDataForSubTask($oldData, $newData, $request,$this->writeHistoryLog);
            $eventKey = $changeData->checkChange();
            $this->setLog($oldData, $newData, 'PUT', self::PUT, 'SubTask');
        }

        if ($newData instanceof SupplierUsers) {
            $newSupplierUser = new HowChangeDataSupplierUsers($newData,$oldData, $request);
            $eventKey = $newSupplierUser->checkChange();
            $this->setLog($oldData, $newData, 'PUT', self::PUT, 'SupplierUser');
        }

        return $eventKey;
    }

    public function postExceptions($newData, $request, $eventKey = array()):array
    {
        if ($newData instanceof SupplierUsers) {
            $createData = new CreateSuppleirUser($newData);
            $eventKey = $createData->checkCreate();
        }
        if ($newData instanceof SupplierCarLocations){
            $createData = new CreateSupplierCarLocation($newData);
            $eventKey = $createData->checkCreate();
        }
        return $eventKey;
    }

    public function setLog($oldData, $newData, string $type, string $text, string $entity)
    {
        $this->monologApiService->notice($text . $entity, array(
            "Entity" => $entity,
            "Type" => $type,
            "newData" => (array)$newData,
            "oldData" => (array)$oldData
        ));
        return;
    }

}
```

There is a commend line which is above section working genericEvent under bellow here you can see,
When I throw Exception in GenericEvent database writing must be stoped. İt is still writing.

Generic Event class:

```
namespace App\EventSubscriber\SubTask;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Exception\RuntimeException;
use App\Entity\DRSA\Options;
use App\Entity\DRSA\SubTask;
use App\Entity\DRSA\SupplierCarQueues;
use App\Entity\DRSA\SupplierCars;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\GenericEvent;

class CreateSupplierCar implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $entityManager;

    /**
     * @var EventDispatcherInterface
     */
    private $dispatcher;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->dispatcher = $dispatcher;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            Event::Create_SupplierCar_For_SubTask => [
                ['setStatus', 100]
            ]
        ];
    }


    public function setStatus(GenericEvent $event)
    {
        $data = (object)$event->getSubject();
        if (isset($data->request->status)){
            throw new RuntimeException("Status araç durumuna göre otomatik belirlenecektir. Status göndermeyiniz.");
        }
        $queue = $this->entityManager->getRepository(SupplierCarQueues::class)->findBy(array("car"=>$data->new->supplierCars,"status"=>1));
        if (count($queue)>=3){
            throw new RuntimeException("Araç kuyruğuna 3 den fazla iş atanamaz.");
        }
        $newQueue = new SupplierCarQueues();
        $newQueue->setCreateDate(new \DateTime());
        $newQueue->setSubTask($this->entityManager->getRepository(SubTask::class)->find($data->old->id));
        $newQueue->setCar($this->entityManager->getRepository(SupplierCars::class)->find($data->new->supplierCars->id));
        $newQueue->setStatus($this->entityManager->getRepository(Options::class)->find(1));
        $subTask = $this->entityManager->getRepository(SubTask::class)->find($data->old->id);
        if ($queue){
            $newQueue->setPriority(100-count($queue));
            $subTask->setStatus($this->entityManager->getRepository(Options::class)->find(21));
        }else{
            $newQueue->setPriority(100);
            $subTask->setStatus($this->entityManager->getRepository(Options::class)->find(22));
        }
        if (empty($data->type)){
            $mixArray = array("old"=>$data->old,"new"=>$subTask,"request"=>$data->request,"type"=>"Auto");
            $newEvent = new GenericEvent($mixArray);
            $this->dispatcher->dispatch(Event::Change_Status_For_SubTask,$newEvent);
        }
        $this->entityManager->persist($newQueue);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
        $this->entityManager->persist($subTask);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }


}
```

**I need to stop database write after exception.**

Answer (score 0):

what is your problem exactly ? Is your exception throwned (ie. do you see the exception message in your browser) ?

When you throw an exception and you don't catch it, it should bubble up to the main Symfony controller and return an error. 
Everything that has already been written to DB should be written (it is already there ), the rest should not.

Are you sure your `setStatus` is executed ?

Answer (score 0):

what is your problem exactly ? Is your exception throwned (ie. do you see the exception message in your browser) ? ---> Yes I can see exception on postman

When you throw an exception and you don't catch it, it should bubble up to the main Symfony controller and return an error. Everything that has already been written to DB should be written (it is already there ), the rest should not.  --> throw Exception not problem. It is working. database writing must stop after exception. But working.

Are you sure your setStatus is executed ? --> Yes it is executing.

in first Code window you can see genericevent dispatcher working  inside of  SystemControl function.This generic event giving throw exception. But after throwing exception all system must be stoped and database write should be stop.Some how it's not stopping. PUT request return response is Exception and database updated.database shouldn't enter any records.It must be return response is Exception and database not will be updated.Normally, it should stop reading code when I throw an exception in this part. 
therefore, it continues to read the code, causing incorrect data entry.